# Mysql has failed in my raspberry pi running raspian

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, lamp

I'm currently using wordpress on my raspberry pi. Just recently I tried to connect to the apache web server and got an interesting error. `Error establishing a database connection.` So I did some searching around and fiddling with my raspberry pi and found out that the mysql service isn't running anymore. I did a `systemctl status mysql.service -l` and got this crazy long output that is in an alien language to me:

```
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server /etc/init.d/mysql[5630]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server /etc/init.d/mysql[5630]: [61B blob data]
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server /etc/init.d/mysql[5630]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server /etc/init.d/mysql[5630]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server /etc/init.d/mysql[5630]:
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server mysql[4891]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Jun 17 22:06:58 Latridell_Server systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

Can someone please make something of this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

-A flailing noob in a world of mysql and linux

Comment: Well that could mean anything. You're going to have to search for MySQL's own logfile to find out what's wrong. I'd start looking in `/var/log` (it could have its own file or be a part of `syslog` or `messages` or elsewhere completely). If you can't, logging is probably disabled or not properly configured. Finding out why MySQL isn't starting can be a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

Please do this commend.

`sudo service mysql stop`
`/usr/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql`

then
`sudo service mysql start`

Comment: If you look at the error code, you can see that there is no error in starting the db server.
It's very similar to what I've been through, but in my case it was due to user permissions during the mysql-database installation process.
if this code did not fix it, you must specify the db directory directly as below code.
`#/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql -–datadir=/dir/what/you/want`